# D-LINK Wireless and Eset Smart Security

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ics, nod32

I Bought a D-LINK Wireless Modem (G DWA-510 Desktop Adaptor) and installed it on my PC to make my home wireless network, but when other devices (laptop and mobile) want to connect to my wireless network, they can't until I disable my anti virus firewall (`right click on Eset smart security icon and click disable firewall`).

Can any one help me solve this problem and set my Eset settings so that there is no need to turn the firewall off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used the Eset Firewall so cannot be sure, however I would make sure that your lan is set up properly in it and if it has any sort of Wizard, re run it.

It is possible you were using a 192.168.0.x and now using a different one (192.168.1.x or 10.0.0.x) and the firewall may think you are under attack and blocking everything.

I know that some firewalls have this behaviour as I had something similar a few days ago on a Symantec one after installing a new router.